# Can't save a location due to null object error

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My goal is to save and retrieve a location from Google Maps in firebase database. My app crashes when I try to load the map where I am supposed to save a location. It keeps returning the error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference

Here's the part of the code where the error is happening:

```
profDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            latt = snapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class); //This is where the error happens
            longg = snapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
            String stallname = snapshot.child("StallName").getValue().toString();

            LatLng newLocation = new LatLng(latt, longg);

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
              .position(newLocation)
              .title(stallname));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
```

Here's a screenshot of my database structure without the latitude & longitude being inputted:

[image: without latlng]

Here's what's supposed to look like when a location is saved:

[image: saved location]

Answer (score 0):

This means that the data stored in `snapshot.child("latitude")` is not a valid `Double`.

The most likely thing I can think of (without seeing your actual data) is that you have a string there, which *contains* the value. In that case you can get the double value out of it with:

```
latt = Double.valueOf(snapshot.child("latitude").getValue(String.class));
```

Comment: There isn't any data stored there yet actually, because I have to save a location first which will be the data that should be stored in the database. But I can't save a location because the error appears before I can store a data.

Comment: I'm not completely clear yet (an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be really helpful). But if you want to check if the child node exists, you can do so with: `snapshot.child("latitude").exists()`. Note that `dataSnapshot` and `snapshot` itself will always exist in your `onDataChange`, so you don't need an `exists()` check on those.